# Two loop-carried dependency chain. Which one matters?

Tags: performance, optimization, x86

My CPU is IvyBridge.
Let's consider example from Agner's Fog optimizing_assembly, I mean. 12.6 chapter and the 12.10a example:

```
    movsd xmm2, [x] 
    movsd xmm1, [one] 
    xorps xmm0, xmm0  
    mov eax, coeff    

    L1:
        movsd xmm3, [eax] ; c[i]
        mulsd xmm3, xmm1  ; c[i]*x^i
        mulsd xmm1, xmm2  ; x^(i+1)
        addsd xmm0, xmm3  ; sum += c[i]*x^i
        add   eax, 8
        cmp eax, coeff_end
        jb L1
```

And the frontend is not a bottleneck ( it is obvious because of the latency of multiplication).

We have two loop-carried dependency ( I skipped `add eax, 8`):
1. `mulsd xmm1, xmm2` latency of 5 cycles
2. `addsd xmm0, xmm3` latency of 3 cycles

Btw, I have a proble to decide: Should I sum up ( 5 + 3 = 8) or to get the greatest, i.e. 5 cycle?

I've tested it for 10000000 elements array. And it takes 6.7 cycle per iteration ( according to perf) and 5.9 cycles per iteration according to Agners' tool.

Please explain why it does take 6/7 cycles instead of just 5 cycles?

Comment: You can't ignore the cost of loading the data from RAM.

Comment: Can you try to write more useful question titles?  "Loop too slow" doesn't tell anyone anything except that you should have used the [optimization] or [performance] tags.  Some of your previous questions have had really terrible titles, too, like "Too much cycles".

Comment: Looks like the longest loop-carried dep chain is the `mulsd xmm1, xmm2`.  Next iteration's `mul` can start before this iteration's `addsd` finishes, because it doesn't depend on `xmm0`.  The other instructions depend on that loop-carried mul chain, but they fork off a separate dep chain for each iteration (except for the `addsd`, which is also loop-carried, but lower latency).

Comment: Thanks :). I improved my post :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably resource conflicts are sometimes delaying the loop-carried `mulsd`.  uop scheduling chooses oldest-first (out of uops that have their inputs ready), not critical-path-first, so the `mulsd xmm3, xmm1` probably steals the execution port and delays the loop-carried `mulsd xmm1, xmm2` by a cycle occasionally.

There are probably also occasional pipeline stalls from cache misses, since hardware prefetching doesn't work across page boundaries.  Test for this by putting an outer repeat-loop around an inner loop over ~128kiB of data (1/2 L2 cache size).

prefetch should have no problem keeping up with your loop normally, though: One 64b load per 5 cycles is about 1/5th of main memory bandwidth.

You could also use `float` instead of `double`

---

Does your data have any denormals?  Those are slow [(but NaN isn't, with SSE)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31875464/huge-performance-difference-26x-faster-when-compiling-for-32-and-64-bits/31879376#31879376).